Ajax Call with Separate WooCommerce PHP Function
I am trying to build a custom page where user fills his product criteria by clicking on/off switch buttons and then when user clicks a "Submit" button, the desired product will be visible using a custom woocommerce shortcode.
My jquery is collecting switch button values in order to send the desired product id to server side conditionally. I have a separate php function called test.php to build my custom shortcode.
Ajax call seems to work, when button is clicked, console returns the desired value from jquery.
However, if I try wc_get_product() console returns 500 error. Tried to load Wordpress by using something like require( '/wp-content/wp-load.php' ); or assign my function inside functions.php without luck.
I think I miss something vital, any ideas would be highly appreciated.
Here is my query function:
function test_text_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {

    $("#Lease-Test-Button").click(function() {
       // bla bla code
       var SuperID = '3197';
      $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-content/themes/vantage-child/test.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            SuperID: SuperID,
        }, 
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Success");
        }
     });            
   });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'test_text_javascript');

and this is my test.php
<?php

if(isset($_POST['SuperID'])) {
    $SuperID = $_POST['SuperID'];
    echo $SuperID;
    
    $product = wc_get_product($SuperID);
    if ($product) {
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $product_price = $product->get_price();
        echo "<div>Product Name: $product_name</div>";
        echo "<div>Product Price: $product_price</div>";
    } else {
        echo "Product not found.";
    }
    
} else {
    echo "Error: SuperID not received";
}

?>


You should not target a "stand-alone" PHP script with your request to begin with, but use the proper mechanism to do AJAX in WordPress. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/
